# How do you design a bridge rectifier circuit?

Tags: diodes, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I am trying to design a bridge rectifier circuit (without capacitor). When I try measuring and graphing the output and input, the input looks fine but the output is just a straight line. Did I design the circuit wrong? Or am I probing the wrong spot? [image: Bridge Rectifier Circuit]

[image: Graph. Green is input, blue is output]

[image: What the output is supposed to look like]

Comment: The output of bridge rectifier is the voltage on R1 (that's it - between it's leads)

Comment: voltage probing is always between two points, so you need to know where your second point is for each measurement.

Comment: Try also increasing the input voltage ac level to a few volts.

Comment: In a simulator voltages are defined **relative to ground**. I do not see a **ground** connection in your circuit so the simulator cannot determine the voltages. And this isn't "design", this is "analyzing a circuit in a simulator".

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. That was the issue.

Comment: @JohnStewart Possibly, you would still have seen a (kind of) rectified waveform if you (could) plot the blue voltage probe in a seperate window, but I don't know the simulation software you use. The plot scale now is from -600 mV to 600 mV: waveforms in the order of 25 **u**V will be shown as a straight line